# jquery - I need to open hidden content on page in a new window

Tags: jquery

Hey everyone, I am working on a site in which I do not have control over the HTML. I need to use jQuery to grab some content that is hidden in a div and open it in a new window. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any way for you to share some sample code or the website you are viewing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't yet have the rep to make edits or post links. I'll post a small code snippet here:

Comment: <div class = "news_title">
    <a class ="news_link"></a>
</div>
<div class = "news_description" style="display:none;">Content Goes Here</div>

This code is repeated 8 times on the site and I need to add change the display of the div as it corresponds to it's link. I am unable to edit any of the classes and the ids change each month as new content is generated. Basically I need to figure out how to only open one of these links at once while keeping the others hidden unless their anchor tag is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it in a new browser window, or would a dialog box work?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thanks, dialog box will work fine. I also have another issue. I am doing this for several articles on the page that have hidden divs. I need a way to target these without using specific IDs or classes as they update every month. I need each one to open when it's corresponding link is clicked. I imagine that I need to use some kind of loop to only allow one to open at a time. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it though. Is looping the way to go here?

Comment: You could put them inside a container with a sepcific id for reference, then loop through them to set them up.